# filtering using array in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am kinda in the lost here.
I am trying to use a list of words saved as text file, and place them in an array to use as a filter.
I am able to accomplish the task IF I write the words individually in an array (ex. @words = "one", "two", "three"), BUT if i pull them out from a text and place them in an array using the Get-Content cmdlet, I am not getting the same result as to placing them individually. What could be the reason?

here are the things I had tried

```
$filterpath = "D:\folder\text.txt"

$extractedwords = Get-Content -path $filterpath

$excludedWords = @(extractedwords)
```

==========

```
$filterpath = "D:\folder\text.txt"

$excludedwords = Get-Content -path @($filterpath)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$extractedwords` already _is_ an array of lines - except if there happens to be just _one_ line - to also cover the latter case, use `$extractedwords = @(Get-Content -path $filterpath)`, or, for best performance, `$extractedwords = Get-Content -ReadCount 0 $filterPath` (reads all lines at once, and returns an array; without `-ReadCount 0`, the lines are _streamed_ one by one, and _then_ collected in an array).

Comment: As an aside: `@(extractedwords)` should be `@($extractedwords)`, though `[array] $extractedwords` would be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

`Get-Content` already returns an array.
If your file is one-word-per-line, you are golden with `$extractedwords = Get-Content -path $filterpath`

As suggested by @mklement0 : if the file is relatively big evaluate using `$extractedwords = Get-Content -ReadCount 0 -path $filterpath` as it will read the file as a whole instead of line-by-line.

Last: if you plan to MODIFY the resulting array then it'd be better to cast it as a `List` instead: `$ExtractedWords=[System.Collections.Generic.List[string]](Get-Content -Path $FilterPath)` (also with `-ReadCount 0` if necessary)